# Getting CORS error on accessing public data from Notion API

Tags: cors, fetch-api, notion-api

I'm trying to fetch data from a public page on notion.
From the endpoint, POST -
`https://www.notion.so/api/v3/loadPageChunk`

```
bodyData = {
 "pageId": "1ecb80f4-c484-4cb8-a3bb-7f63cf252b6c",
 "limit": 50,
 "cursor": {
 "stack": []
  },
"chunkNumber": 0,
"verticalColumns": false
}
```

using the above as request body.

I was able to receive an output, when I hit this endpoint from a client (Thunder Client / Postman ).

But when I'm trying to do the same programmatically I'm getting a CORS error.

Note- This is not an official end point from notion.

I want to know, if output can be achieved from a client ( which too has different origin ) can it also be achieved programmatically ?

Comment: Yes.  You can have the notion maintainers to add in your URL to the allowed origins.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)